# How do I capture a KeyUp event on Windows in MAUI

Tags: maui, maui-windows

In Xamarin Forms, I was able to do this via the following code in the App.xaml.cs file in the UWP project.

Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyUp += CoreWindow_KeyUp;

I understand that because MAUI is Windows Desktop, not UWP, Window.Current is always null.  So how do I capture the KeyUp event now?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, MAUI Windows is a Desktop app. And `Window.Current`  will return 'null in a Desktop project. According to [Core unsupported classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-supported-api#core-unsupported-classes), consider using the InputKeyboardSource.GetKeyStateForCurrentThread method provided by WinUI 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Use a Page Handler in the MauiProgram class

Add to CreateMauiApp method:

```
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.PageHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyPageCustomization", (handler, view) =>
            {
    #if WINDOWS
                //Need to use PreviewKeyUp instead of KeyUp to capture the Enter Key
                handler.PlatformView.PreviewKeyUp += Windows_PreviewKeyUp;
    #endif
            });
```

Add method:

```
#if WINDOWS
private static void Windows_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input.KeyRoutedEventArgs e)    
         {
            //Code
         }
#endif
```